# What is the easiest way to draw line in absolute layput vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, absolutelayout

After creating absoluteLayout object what is the easiest way to draw line between two objects in that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to use absoluteLayout for drawing lines, but instead one of the Canvas addons:

- https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/canvas
- https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/canvas-plus

Depending of your use-case you also want to draw whatever you are drawing directly in the client and not from the server.

For your question is very limited I can't give you more guidance.

If you still want to use absoluteLayout and drawing lines, you should go with a simple div-element (you could for example add an empty Label or whatever) and style it via CSS so it looks like a line. You won't be able to "connect" your two objects easily, though - use a canvas for that purpose.